# Traditional pdf view issues

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, developer-story

- The line breaks disappears on the cv. It makes for a long paragraph if the personal statement contains many lines. Could it be formatted like the personal statement itself? Is it by design?

[image]

[image]

- Apparently `<li>`'s are textually imported from the markdown in the careers cv. I clicked the import from your career cv, and in the pdf view they appear as textual `<li>`. Writing it back in markdown settles it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your report. This has now been fixed and will be up with our next prod build <3 The markdown was being rendered as-is, instead of baked into html beauty.