# Developer Story pdf contains markdown source

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story

I made my developer story by importing my careers content where the personal statement is written in markdown.

When exporting as a "traditional pdf" the statement is the markdown source instead of the expected result.

[image]

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320088/traditional-pdf-view-issues